# Combining and compressing using "tar czf" and "tar + gzip". The resultant file in both cases is packname.tar.gz but why sizes are different?

Tags: linux, compression, gzip, tar, archive

There are three text files. test1, test2 and test3 with file sizes as:  
test1 - 121 B 
test2 -   4 B 
test3 -  26 B 
I am trying to combine and compress these files using different methods.  
  
**Method-A** 
Combine the files using **tar** and then compress it using **gzip**.  
`$tar cf testpack1.tar test1 test2 test3` 
`$gzip testpack1.tar` 
Output is testpack1.tar.gz with size 276 B
**Method-B** 
Combine and compress the files using **tar**.  
`$tar czf testpack2.tar.gz test1 test2 test3` 
Output is testpack2.tar.gz with size 262 B
Why the size of the two files are different? 
B mean bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you un-gzip the archive created by your step B, I bet it will be 10240 bytes. Reason for such difference in size is that tar will align compressed archive to block size (using zero character), but it will not align the uncompressed archive. Here is excerpt from the GNU tar documentation:

```
-b blocks
--blocking-factor=blocks 
Set record size to blocks * 512 bytes. 
This option is used to specify a blocking factor for the archive. When
reading or writing the archive, tar, will do reads and writes of the
archive in records of block*512 bytes. This is true even when the
archive is compressed. Some devices requires that all write operations
be a multiple of a certain size, and so, tar pads the archive out to
the next record boundary. The default blocking factor is set when tar
is compiled, and is typically 20. Blocking factors larger than 20
cannot be read by very old versions of tar, or by some newer versions
of tar running on old machines with small address spaces. With a
magnetic tape, larger records give faster throughput and fit more data
on a tape (because there are fewer inter-record gaps). If the archive
is in a disk file or a pipe, you may want to specify a smaller
blocking factor, since a large one will result in a large number of
null bytes at the end of the archive.
```

You can create same compressed tar archive like this:

```
tar -b 20 -cf test.tar test1 test2 test3
gzip test.tar
```